# Formating proc freq output table in SAS

Tags: sas, format

I have the following data

```
DATA HAVE;
input year dz area;
cards;
2000 1 08
2000 1 06
2000 1 06
;
run;

 

proc freq data=have;
table area*dz / norow nocol;
run;
```

I get the following output

[image: Priyamvada07_0-1616740380414.png]

I would like to format it to put frequency in one column and percent in another column and I don't want the total column. Is there a way to do it?

Thank you!

Comment: Try the LIST option instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Try adding the LIST option to get a different layout:

   ```
   proc freq data=have;
    table area*dz / norow nocol LIST;
   run;
   ```
2. Pipe it to a data set and format as desired:

   ```
   proc freq data=have;
    table area*dz / norow nocol LIST out=want;
   run;
   proc print data=want;run;
   ```
3. Use [PROC TABULATE](https://documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=pgmsascdc&cdcVersion=9.4_3.5&docsetId=proc&docsetTarget=p09qs3m2djd7bgn1g464ln0pr48c.htm&locale=en) instead (not shown), which allows you more control over your layout and formats.